# Trying to understand question in exercise about relations

Tags: logic, relations

I'm working on my own through How to Prove It by Daniel J. Velleman and I am trying to understand what is being asked for exercise 9 in section 4.4:

Suppose $R$ is a partial order on $A$ and $S$ is a partial order on $B$. Define a relation $L$ on $A \times B$ as follows: $L = \{ ((a,b),(a',b')) \in (A \times B) \times (A \times B) ~ | ~ aRa', ~ \text{and if} ~ a = a' \text{then} ~  bSb'\}$.

Specifically, I am trying to understand the definition of the relation $L$.

Must $a = a'$ for any pair of ordered pairs to belong to $L$?

As a specific example, let $A = \{1, 2\}$ and $B = \{3, 4\}$. Therefore, $A \times B = \{(1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4)\}$. Let $R = \{(1,1), (2,2), (1,2) \}$ and $B = \{ (3,3), (4,4), (3,4) \}$.

Now in this specific example is $L = \{ ((1,3), (1,3)), ~((1,4),(1,4)), ~ ((1,3),(1,4)), ~ ((2,3),(2,3)), ~ ((2,4),(2,4)), ~ ((2,3),(2,4))\}$?

---

Update: Thanks everyone for the helpful replies to my question.

A little more context to my question:

One of the reasons I am having difficulty with the definition of $L$ is when trying to use it when showing that $L$ is a partial order on $A \times B$.

The definition of $L$ has a logical form of $P \land (O \implies Q)$, where $P$ is $aRa'$, $O$ is $a = a$, and $Q$ is $bSb'$.

Now to show, for example, that $L$ is a reflexive relation on $A \times B$ we must show that $\forall (a, b) \in A \times B ((a,b),(a,b)) \in L$. To do this, let $(a,b)$ be arbitrary and suppose $(a,b) \in A \times B$. Thus, $a \in A$ and $aRa$. This shows the $P$ part of $P \land (O \implies Q)$ from above.

Now we must show that $a = a \implies bSb$. The method we are shown to do this in the book is to assume the antecedent and prove the consequent. So assume $a = a$, but this does not tell us anything about $bSb$. So I'm not sure what to do from here.

Perhaps I should open a new question for the stuff in the update part of this question?

---

After reviewing the comments below and thinking about it more here is another attempt to show that $L$ is a reflexive relation on $A \times B$:

Let $(a,b)$ be arbitrary and suppose $(a,b) \in A \times B$. Thus $a \in A$ and because $R$ is a partial order on $A$, then $aRa$. Now assume $a = a$. We know that since $(a,b) \in A \times B$ then $b \in B$. Since $S$ is a partial order on $B$, then $bSb$. Therefore, if $a = a$ then $bSb$. Since $aRa$ and if $a = a$ then $bSb$, then $((a,b),(a,b)) \in L$. Since $(a,b)$ was arbitrary we can conclude $L$ is a reflexive relation on $A \times B$. $\square$

Comment: Perhaps it would help to have some motivation.  Think about how you alphabetize words.  First you compare the first letters.  If the first letters are the same, then you move on to the second letters, and so on.  Do you see that the definition of $L$ is based on a similar idea?

Comment: @DanVelleman thanks for the comment. I think I see the connection your are talking about. One of the reasons I am having trouble with the definition of $L$ is trying to use it in showing that $L$ is a partial order on $A \times B$. I have added in some more information to the question to explain this in more detail.

Comment: "The definition of $L$ has a logical form of $P\wedge (R \implies Q)$, where $P$ is $aRa′$, $R$ is $a=a$, and $Q$ is $bSb′$."  This is false.  First, you have re-used 
"$R$" with different semantics, so let's go with "The definition of $L$ has a logical form of $P\wedge (O \implies Q)$, where $P$ is $aRa′$, $O$ is $a=a$, and $Q$ is $bSb′$."  You do not *prove* the definition of a set.  You are given the definition of the set -- this predicate is true for every member of the set.

Comment: In the Update, you say "now we must show that $a=a \Rightarrow bSb'$."  That's not right; what you need to show is that $a=a \Rightarrow bSb$.

Comment: @EricTowers Yes, I did use $R$ in two different ways. Thanks for pointing that out. I have now changed it to $P \land (O \implies Q)$. To show that a pair of ordered pairs is in the relation $L$ we must show that they meet the definition of $L$ right? That is what I was trying to do in the Update section.

Comment: @DanVelleman Yes, you are correct. I must show that $a = a \implies bSb$ in showing that $L$ is a reflexive relation on $A \times B$. I have corrected that in the update section. I have also added in another attempt at a proof that $L$ is a reflexive relation on $A \times B$. Does it look correct?

Comment: @mmm3: Yes, the new proof that $L$ is reflexive looks good.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x := ((a,b)\times(a',b'))$. Whether $x \in L$, depends on whether $aRa'$ and whether $bSb'$.  There are 4 possibilities for the latter two. Let's make a table.

$\begin{array}{r|cc}
& bSb' & \lnot bSb' \\ \hline
aRa' & & \\
\lnot aRa'
\end{array}$

The definition for $L$ is an *and* condition which starts with $aRa'$, so we can exclude the $\lnot aRa'$ cases.

$\begin{array}{r|cc}
& bSb' & \lnot bSb' \\ \hline
aRa' &  & \\
\lnot aRa' & x \notin L & x \notin L
\end{array}$

Further, the definition for $L$ states that in the case where $aRa'$, we also need to consider whether $a=a'$, so we need to split the $aRa'$ case.

$\begin{array}{r|cc}
& bSb' & \lnot bSb' \\ \hline
a=a',aRa' &  & \\
a \ne a',aRa' &  & \\
\lnot aRa' & x \notin L & x \notin L
\end{array}$

The second part of the conditional says if $a=a'$ then $bSb'$, so we can fill in the top row.

$\begin{array}{r|cc}
& bSb' & \lnot bSb' \\ \hline
a=a',aRa' & x\in L & x \notin L \\
a \ne a',aRa' &  & \\
\lnot aRa' & x \notin L & x \notin L
\end{array}$

Finally, the if conditional is true when the hypothesis is false, that is when $a \ne a'$, so $aRa'$ makes the first half of the conditional true and $a \ne a'$ makes  the second half true, and we finish out the table.

$\begin{array}{r|cc}
& bSb' & \lnot bSb' \\ \hline
a=a',aRa' & x\in L & x \notin L \\
a \ne a',aRa' & x\in L & x\in L \\
\lnot aRa' & x \notin L & x \notin L
\end{array}$

Answer (score 2):

I would interpret it as follows: The relation goes as follows ((a,b),(a',b')) where aRa', except if a= a'. If a= a', then only the following relations exist ((a,b), (a',b')) where aRa' and bSb'.

Comment: I changed the answer a bit - I'm sorry for using weird phrasing. I didn't quite take the time to understand your notation. Now it should be consistent.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense to me now.

Comment: One small correction - I think the very last part of your answer should be $bSb'$, not $bRb'$.

Comment: @mmm3 Your right! I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

> Must =′ for any pair of ordered pairs to belong to ?

No. You can have pairs $(a,b)\times (a',b')$ where $a\neq a'$ as long as $aRa'$.

Using your example, since $(1,2)\in R$, then (1,3)x(2,4)$\in L$.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, thanks for the answer. So to build upon your answer, since $(1,2) \in R$ then $((1,3),(2,3)) \in L$ and $((1,4),(2,4)) \in L$?

Comment: Exactly. Generally put, it would be all pairs of the form $(1,b)\times(2,b')$.